# How do I determine what the valid range is for CGPoint on a device when using locationInView of touch events?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitouch, touchesbegan

I know the iPhone has 480 x 320 and iPad is 1024 x 768 but I don't know how to determine that programmatically.  I'd appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UITouch*yourTouchNameHere = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint yourPointNameHere=[touch locationInView:self.view];
```

This automatically means that the touch is on the screen, so any touch-point returned would be valid, but still the code below might help your understanding:

---

### Receive Screen size with: `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size`

Height of iOSDevice in pixels returned with:

```
[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height
```

Width of iOSDevice in pixels returned with:

```
[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width
```

Is the iOSDevice an iPhone with:

```
if([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){}
```

Is the iOSDevice an iPad with:

```
if([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){}
```

---

*Another [stackOverflow question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779221/in-iphone-app-how-to-detect-the-screen-resolution-of-the-device) shows you could also use*

Return the entire screen resolution in points (320x400, etc.) with:

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
```

Return the screen resolution scale with:

```
CGFloat screenScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
```

Another way to get the pixel width and height with the two above lines included:

```
CGSize screenSize = CGSizeMake(screenBounds.size.width * screenScale, screenBounds.size.height * screenScale);
```