# Screen width and height

Tags: ios, height, width, resolution, measure

I want to get the width and height of the screen, with this code ...

```
float screenWidth = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
float screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
NSLog(@"%f %f",screenWidth, screenHeight);
```

I get always 320 480 , but these aren't the true measures of the simulator. Now I'm testing on  a retina simulator with more resolution, but i always get 320 480

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your answer can be found here: [in iPhone App How to detect the screen resolution of the device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779221/in-iphone-app-how-to-detect-the-screen-resolution-of-the-device)

Its the scale that interests you as well. Use `CGFloat screenScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];` to find out the scale.

When positioning elements your points should always be in non-retina scale. Size of the screen for 3.5 inch is 320x480 units and 320x568 for the 4 inch screen. The pixel resolution is times two for retina screens.