# Disable native resolution ONLY for iPhone 6 Plus

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I need my app to not use iPhone 6 Plus' native resolution and rather scale up from iPhone 5/6.

I have removed the Launch Screen File and cleared "Retina HD 5.5" from the Launch Image, yet when people run it on iPhone 6 Plus, the app is still using its native resolution. 
Note that removing the "Retina HD 5.5" was sufficient to bypass iTunesConnect App Screenshots validation for iPhone 6 Plus, yet the app itself is not honoring that.

Is there anything else to remove to eliminate iPhone 6 Plus native resolution?

Comment: Egads, I didn't know that was possible! Is there some issue with app compatibility?

Comment: The app scales perfectly fine on 6+ resolution (using layout constraints all over), but it's just too much extra white space in a couple of places and I'd prefer a more tightly-spaced, zoomed-in iPhone6 version for 6+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not. You can only support 6 and 6 Plus together or none of them. As soon as you use the Launch Screen File Xcode assumes you want to support them.

Comment: That's what I was fearing. Thanks for the confirmation. I'll just adjust some layout constraints to not go beyond certain max width/aspect ratio for elements that look too large/white-spaced on 6+.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't know why you want to do that, but there are some tricks to resize fields and buttons (I assume you want to do that)

You should be able to determine the screen size/native screen size so you can resize your CGRects for example.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4779415/2826164

create an global function or variable to multiply your current width and heigth by, for example native width of 6+ = 1242*0,60306 = 750 native.

i'm not sure if you need 1080 or 1242 because of downscaling

[More info about iphone 6+ resolution](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/iphone-6-screens-demystified)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Planning to adjust layout constraints to accomplish just that (eliminate funny-looking white space). I think for certain apps iPhone 6+ is closer to a tablet size than a phone and optimally needs a slightly different UI layout to make good use of all the extra space.