# How to find out how many pixels a point has for current device

Tags: ios, iphone

In iOS, I want to know at runtime, how many pixels a point has.

Answer (score 2):

An iOS point is equivalent to 1/163 of an inch (160 android) and represents a visual 
perception entity for humans according to iphone 1 native resolution.

So a point here depends on pixel resolution AND physical display size.

You have to COMBINE a device detection(*) with the native pixel resolution detection(**)
and hold a internal list of devices and their physical screen sizes in inch(***) because
there is no function for that yet.

(*) + (**) already explained here:

[iOS - How to get device make and model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197509/ios-how-to-get-device-make-and-model)

and here:

[in iPhone App How to detect the screen resolution of the device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779221/in-iphone-app-how-to-detect-the-screen-resolution-of-the-device)

examples:

1. detect an iphone 5 (*)
2. your app knows iphone6 means a ~1.9632inch display width (***)
3. you calculate 1.963 * 163 = ~ 320 points in width
4. you detect the resolution pixels in width 640 (**)
5. now you know the pixel:point ratio = 640/320 = 2

another in short.

detect iphone 6 means a ~2.54inch display width * 163 = ~414px 
and resolution of 1242 so pixel:point ratio = 1242/414 = 3